# Cookie spec is set to outdated RFC2109spec RFC2965spec and netscape spec in apache HttpClient4.4.4

Tags: apache, apache-httpclient-4.x

Although RPF6965spec is the latest development in cookie management, then also apache HttpClient 4.4.4 uses above mentioned spec as default. Why cookie spec should be set to STANDARD to use RPF6965spec ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For backward-compatibility with previous versions Apache HttpClient 4.5.x uses a cookie policy that automatically selects `Netscape`, `RFC 2109` or `RFC 2965` specification depending on cookie composition.

As of version 5.0 Apache HttpClient will use `RFC 6965` policy by default.

Comment: I checked for 5.0 and still it uses `Netscape, RFC 2109 or RFC 2965` as default

Comment: No, it does not. Those specs have been removed in 5.0.

Comment: can you provide reference for the same

Comment: https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/tree/master/httpclient5/src/main/java/org/apache/hc/client5/http/impl/cookie